# How to check if some entity object fits to the Query with Spring Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Let's say I have an mongo collection entity

```
class MyEntity {
  private String name;

  public String getName() {return name;}
  public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
}
```

and some instance of MyName with name "supermario":

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.setName("supermario");
```

and some spring-data mongo Query which looks on entities with supernames:

```
Query q= new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").regex("super.*"));
```

Is there some possibility to check if the MyEntity entity fits into criteria of the Query q?

Comment: apply the regex to your entity and check if it is correctly returned

Comment: You should validate your beans with something other than `Query` object, use hibernate validator for example -> http://hibernate.org/validator/